# What are the benefits of fresh produce, and how long does it last?

Tags: story-of-seasons

The first set of crops I harvested were all referred to as "Fresh". I don't recall this system being present in previous games, so I'm not sure how it works. I'm assuming the effect expires after a few days, and that it could extended if I bought a fridge, but I don't have any data on it (I'm just guessing). I'm also curious if it's possible to produce to go rotten as well, and if so, what effect that has.

What are the benefits of fresh produce? How long does it last? Can produce eventually go rotten as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fresh crops will sell for a bit more when trading, and slightly improve the quality of cooked dishes.

Freshness lasts for 3 days before becoming "normal" (even if you store them in the fridge). Crops can never go rotten/rancid

if you get a "mystery seeds" from the Wheat Country and it grows in a star, you can extend this freshness period to 60 days by harvesting the star before harvesting the crops (the crops must be ripe)

Comment: Does the fridge serve any purpose, then?

Comment: the fridge is for storage. your bag can only hold 50 items (until upgrade), and 1 fridge holds another 50. Eventually if you are a hoarder like me, you may end up with multiple fridges, one for fish, and one for crops/food.

Comment: So it's not any different from previous harvest moon games.  That's a shame. Part of me was hoping they implemented a whole new fresh  and rotten system which the fridge places a functional role in. Oh well. ACCEPTED.

Comment: @Wipqozn You want Harvest Moon: The Tale of Two Towns. Most farm products and food items will lose freshness over time, depending on the type of item, the current season and how it's stored. http://fogu.com/hm10/basics/star_rank_and_freshness.php